# pull data from MQ using java

Tags: java, listener, ibm-mq

I want to build listener using Java to pull data from IBM MQ once the data existing in the queue, anyone have the idea?

```
.
```

Answer (score 3):

A few tips to get you started;

A bit on an IBM MQ listener here: https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-dev-samples/tree/master/jms/DemoMessageListenerApplication

If you're new to writing apps for IBM MQ, check out the Developer Essentials badge: https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/mq-dev-essentials/